# paypal manager users vs. paypal users

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments, payflowpro, paypal-rest-sdk, payflowlink

I have Payments Pro Payflow Pro (I think) and using manager.paypal.com with "hosted checout pages" right now but I need to change it to process credit cards directly on my website withotu any embeding or redirections.

Account in manager.paypal.com

PayPal Payments Pro Live    --

Hosted Checkout Pages   Live    --

Payflow SDK/API (Full Access)   Live    --

Paypal Express Checkout Live    --

Should be possible via REST API right? https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/accept-credit-cards/

I added new user in manager.paypal.com with role API_FULL_TRANSACTIONS but there is no user_id or secret values anywhere in manager.paypal.com - these 2 values are needed in order to get access_token according to
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/make-your-first-call/

I see these values when logged in as regular paypal user or developer but not in manager.paypal.com

What am I missing?
How manager.paypal.com users are connected to paypal users?

Thanks for help!

Comment: What have you got so far? Show us your work!

Comment: I can't due to client's restriction but hosted solutions via paypal manager work just fine. I have rather general question how manager users are connected to paypal/developer accounts and how to get these user_id and security to pass to REST API

Comment: manager.paypal.com is the merchant-facing website for payflow, which is a product originally developed over a decade ago by another company (Verisign) and subsequently purchased by PayPal. It has been integrated into PayPal and extended to support some, but NOT all, of PayPal's other products. As your question notes you can generate the appropriate type of PayPal API credentials for PayPal's newest REST-based products when logged in to the other PayPal sites (as user or developer). Do that instead of creating & managing the API user in manager.paypal.com.

Comment: Thank you geewiz - I just assumed there must be a connection since manager.paypal.com has user management and special role for it and it's called API_FULL_TRANSACTIONS

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you have a [PayPal Pro 2.0](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/payflow/integration-guide/) account, which gives you full access to both the [PayPal Merchant APIs](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/) as well as the [PayFlow APIs](https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/pp_payflowpro_guide.pdf).

The PayPal Merchant APIs use a USER, PASS, and SIGNATURE in the API request.  The PayFlow API would use the USER, PASS, VENDOR, and PARTNER values that you're seeing with your PayPal Manager account.

For more details, you might be interested in taking a look at this article I wrote about the [history of PayPal Payments Pro](http://www.angelleye.com/paypal-payments-pro-dodirectpayment-vs-payflow/).

Comment: Andrew - thank you for clarification, I would never expect that Paypal can create such a mess... Awesome blog post!